# the form email interface does not display

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

my problem is that the form email  interface does not display

help me please

I create my template email like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
   <record id="entretien_send_email" model="email.template">
     <field name="name">Entretien Send by email</field>
     <field name="model_id" ref="model_appelsoffres_entretien"/>
     <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email or '')|safe}</field>
     <field name="subject">entretien</field>
     <field name="email_to">${(object.candidat.email or '')|safe}</field>
     <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
     <field name="subject">Your request has been submit</field>
     <field name="message"><![CDATA[
    THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL. DO NOT REPLY.

    Hello,

    We are here to inform you that the request [[object.candidat.nom]] est

    de faire un entretien  [[object.titre_evenement]] with the following   data:

| Request - Details
|=========================
| Titre Evenement: [[object.titre_evenement]]
|=========================
| Nom Person: [[object.candidat.nom]]
| Date Entretien: [[object.date_entretien]]
| Heure Debut: [[object.heure_debut]]
|=========================
| Heure Fin: [[object.heure_fin]]


Has not been confirmed and is closed.

If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact your supervisor.

Thank you!]]>
    </field>            
   </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

and in my code python

I called the email template and I set

form view but the form interface is not displayed

```
  class entretien(models.Model):

  _name='appelsoffres.entretien'

  titre_evenement = fields.Char(required=True)

  candidat  =fields.Many2one('appelsoffres.candidature',string="Candidat",required=True)

   email = fields.Char(required=True)

   telephone = fields.Char(required=True)

   portable = fields.Char(required=True)

   state = fields.Selection([

   ('draft', "Brouillon"),

   ('confirmed', "Rendez Vous Planifié"),

   ('done', "Terminé"),

   ('sent', "Envoyé"),

   ], default='draft')

  @api.multi
  def action_draftentretien(self):
  self.state = 'draft'

  @api.multi
  def action_confirmentretien(self):
  self.state = 'confirmed'

  @api.multi
  def action_doneentretien(self):
    self.state = 'done'

  @api.multi
  def send(self):
    self.state = 'sent'
    entretien_send_email = self.env.ref('Appelsdoffres.entretien_send_email',False) 
    entretien_send_email.sudo().with_context().send_mail(self.id‌​, True) 
    result = { 
     'name': 'Send Mail', 
     'view_type': 'form', 
     'view_mode': 'tree,form',
     'views': [('false', 'form'), ], 
     'res_model':'appelsoffres.entretien',
     'context': 'ctx',
     'type': 'ir.actions.act_window', 
     'res_id': '1',
     'target': 'current',
     'context': {}, 
     }
     return result
  entretien()
```

Comment: Are you invoking the `send` method from somewhere?